# How to predict location-keyword combo to fetch ad using machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I need to  build a learning system for mobile ads that should be able to form relevant combinations of locations and keywords so that the api call we make using these to the ad provider fetch us an ad and not an error or empty listing. I am an absolute noob in data mining and hence not very sure of where to start.

For now I am thinking of parsing historical data to get location and keywords that fetched advertisements in the past but that doesn't ensure we'll get an advertisement today for a combination that worked yesterday.

So my questions are,

What should I really do - parsing historical data from logs alone or should there be a way to get keyword locations that will work today?

What model should I use to judge that this is a good combination and should be picked today also?

Thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the premise of the problem . Depending on what the problem is , we can do very well to find out what the appropriate learning algorithm is .

So , you have a couple of ads server that you make API calls to in order to find out what gives you the best result. But what does the result consist of ? Advertisements ? If that is the case , then your mapping is :-

F(location , keyword) => Ads .

If you can clarify that this is the case , we can do something about it. I will update the answer further if you could clarify in programmatic and algorithmic terms what the input/output of this machine learning algorithm should be. I wanted to comment on the answer and not put this out as an answer but due to fewer reps , I cannot do that.

Also , few more questions I have are :-

1) Are the keywords and locations independent of one another ? 
2) Do you have sufficient data to create a learning model from the logs ? 
3) You can try out many algorithms and see which is the best if you could clarify the input/output in machine terms

Comment: thanks, yes by best result I do mean advertisements. We want to guess that for this location and keyword if call the provider of ads, he will have merchants that do want to advertise. If its a bad guess, provider wont return anything.

Comment: further, 
1) yes since we have no way to determine a relation between keywords and locations, they should be deemed independent
2) we have data for 3 days
3) which algorithms should I choose is what i want t know

Comment: So this is the Problem you have right now :-

P(keyword , location) => ads provided . 

Since the keywords are independent ,this problem can very easily be solved by the following approaches :-

1) Create a learning model . (This is standard)
2) Apply Naive Bayes to this learning model
 Or you can apply logictic regression for the same.

Step 1 is applied in almost all the ML algorithms
Step 2 , you can pick up any of these and see how it works out for you.

Comment: There is also a tool available called WEKA http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/  You don't have to implement these algorithms. Just run them through WEKA and find out if it is good or not. Hope this helps